# Issues with redirecting after signup with Devise. What to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added roles to my users and after sign up devise automatically send me back to the homepage. I tried many things from this site and past questions but nothing seems to work. Maybe I'm over thinking it, I'm new here. Essentially I want people who sign up to choose their role, if they're a teacher they go to create a new class ('classrooms#new') and students go to chose their class ('classrooms#index'). I've created a separate registrations controller as suggested and that hasn't worked.

Sign up form (new.html.erb)

```
<div class="authform">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.radio_button :role, 'student' %>
      <%= label :role_student, 'Student' %>

      <%= f.radio_button :role, 'teacher' %>
      <%= label :role_teacher, 'teacher' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Sign Up', :class => 'button right' %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my registrations controller:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    if params[:user][:role] == 'student'
      redirect_to 'classroom#index'
    elsif [:user][:role] == 'teacher'
      redirect_to 'classroom#new'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized
  before_filter :check_role

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    @posts = @user.posts
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    authorize @user
  end

  def check_role
    if params[:user][:role] == 'student'
      redirect_to 'classroom#index'
    elsif [:user][:role] == 'teacher'
      redirect_to 'classroom#new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    # authorize @user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  def create_user_type
  end 

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end
end
```

Edit: Here is my routes page

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'students/new'

  get 'classrooms/new'

  get 'teachers/new'

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  get "edit_profile" => "devise/registrations#edit"
  resources :posts
  resources :teachers

  post 'users/create_user_type' => 'users/create_user_type'
  root to: 'visitors#index'
end
```

I know there is repetitive code with checking roles, I've just been merging answers together (which isn't good I know)

Comment: Try moving `after_sign_up_path_for` to `application_controller`, and adjust the routes appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

use pry gem with binding.pry to check your code & variable content.

Anyway, I suppose that role is an attribute of user so why aren't you checking

```
user.teacher?
user.student?
```

instead of

```
params['']['']
```

resource attribute is persistent instead of params content

Answer (score 0):

I think your registrations controller isn't correct.
If you create your own registrations controller, you want it to override the registrations controller from devise:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if params[:user][:role] == 'student'
   redirect_to 'classroom#index'
  elsif [:user][:role] == 'teacher'
   redirect_to 'classroom#new'
  end
 end
end
```

Then in your routes you must make sure that it also uses your own registrations controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Hope this will help you.